# Updating jekyll using gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I wanted to try out jekyll on Windows. But unfortunately the machine I was trying did not gave me installation rights. So I decided to go with [portable jekyll](https://github.com/madhur/PortableJekyll). I put that repo in my `D:\Program Files\jekyll` folder. Updated the `PATH` in System Environment Variables.

However this jekyll setup has older gems for sass, jekyll. So updated sass. Worked fine. However when I tried updating jekyll with below command

```
gem update jekyll
```

it gave me following errors:

```
Updating jekyll-mentions
Fetching: jekyll-mentions-0.2.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed jekyll-mentions-0.2.1
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll-mentions:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.    
    "D:/Program Files/jekyll/ruby/bin/ruby.exe" extconf.rb
D:/Program Files/jekyll/ruby/bin/ruby.exe: invalid switch in RUBYOPT: -F (RuntimeError)       
Gem files will remain installed in D:/Program Files/jekyll/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.
0.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/Program Files/jekyll/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/yajl-rub
y-1.2.1/ext/yajl/gem_make.out


Updating jekyll-redirect-from
Fetching: jekyll-redirect-from-0.7.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed jekyll-redirect-from-0.7.0
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll-redirect-from:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.    
    "D:/Program Files/jekyll/ruby/bin/ruby.exe" extconf.rb
D:/Program Files/jekyll/ruby/bin/ruby.exe: invalid switch in RUBYOPT: -F (RuntimeError)    
Gem files will remain installed in D:/Program Files/jekyll/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.
0.0/gems/yajl-ruby-1.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/Program Files/jekyll/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/yajl-rub
y-1.2.1/ext/yajl/gem_make.out
```

The rest of the message was as follows:

```
Updating jekyll-sitemap
Fetching: jekyll-sitemap-0.8.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed jekyll-sitemap-0.8.1
Parsing documentation for jekyll-sitemap-0.8.1
Installing ri documentation for jekyll-sitemap-0.8.1
Installing darkfish documentation for jekyll-sitemap-0.8.1
Updating jekyll-watch
Fetching: jekyll-watch-1.2.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed jekyll-watch-1.2.1
Fetching: celluloid-0.16.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed celluloid-0.16.0
Parsing documentation for jekyll-watch-1.2.1
Installing ri documentation for jekyll-watch-1.2.1
Installing darkfish documentation for jekyll-watch-1.2.1
Parsing documentation for celluloid-0.16.0
Installing ri documentation for celluloid-0.16.0
Installing darkfish documentation for celluloid-0.16.0
Gems updated: jekyll-mentions jekyll-redirect-from jekyll-sitemap jekyll-watch c
elluloid
```

Quick google told me to install ruby devkit. So I followed steps [here](http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com/1-ruby-and-devkit/). I downloaded self extracting exe `DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe` from [here](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/). Extracted it in `D:\ProgramFiles\jekyll\ruby-devkit`, then navigated to this directory in command prompt and ran `ruby dk.rb init` as below:

```
D:\Program Files\jekyll\ruby-devkit>ruby dk.rb init  

Initialization complete! Please review and modify the auto-generated 
'config.yml' file to ensure it contains the root directories to all
of the installed Rubies you want enhanced by the DevKit.
```

Now I dont know if the original issue is fixed. When I ran `gem update` for gems with problems, it said nothing to update.

```
C:\Windows\system32>gem update jekyll-mentions
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update

C:\Windows\system32>gem update jekyll-redirect-from
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
```

Please help me understand whats the current state of this setup. Is it fixed afterall? I am completely new to ruby & gems.

Comment: thanks for comment/advice-less downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

- Navigate to your jekyll folder `D:\Program Files\jekyll`
- run `gem cleanup` inside that folder
- after that run `gem update` (also in that folder)

The gemfile included in jekyll should hand you the right gems already. If this does not work, please post you output here.

You also could try `gem install jekyll-mentions` instead of `gem update jekyll-mentions` since it seems like there was an error during installation.

Hope this helps!